# Hypercylic operators with sets of hypercyclic vectors almost covering the space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, banach-spaces, operator-theory

Let $\{T_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a family of hypercylic operators on a separable Banach space $X$.  From the transitivity theorem, we know that $HC(T_i)$, the set of vectors $x \in X$ with $\{T_i^n(x):n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ dense in $X$, is itself a dense $G_{\delta}$ subset of $X$.

It is known, or when is it the case that:

- There exists a finite-dimensional subspace $Y$ of $X$ such that 
  $$
  X-\bigcup_{i \in I} HC(T_i)\subset Y$$
- There is no finite-dimensional subspace $Z\subseteq X$ such that 
  $$
  X-\bigcup_{j=1}^n \, HC(T_{i_j})\subseteq Z
  $$ for any finite sequence $i_1,\dots,i_n$ in $I$